# qt creatorをインストールしたが、応答なしのままとなる。

Tags: qt5

windows7にqt creatorをダウロードqt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_opengl-5.4.1 .exeし、インストールをしました。
その後、起動しましたが、応答なしのままとなってしまいます。
問題の詳細を確認したところ以下のような症状となっております。
解決方法を教えていただきたく。

説明:
  問題が発生したため、このプログラムと Windows の対話が停止しました。

問題の署名:
  問題イベント名:  AppHangB1
  アプリケーション名:    qtcreator.exe
  アプリケーションのバージョン:   0.0.0.0
  アプリケーションのタイムスタンプ: 54e697f0
  停止時の署名:   40be
  停止の種類:    0
  OS バージョン: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4